# Parsing string through dictionary

Tags: python

```
ab='TS_Automation=Manual;TS_Method=Test;TS_Priority=1;TS_Tested_By=rjrjjn;TS_Written_By=SUN;TS_Review_done=No;TS_Regression=No;'

a={'TS_Automation'='Automated',TS_Tested_By='qz9ghv','TS_Review_done'='yes'}
```

I have a string and a dictionary ,Now i have to change the value in string based on the keys of dictionary.If the keys are not there subsequent value need to be removed.As TS_Method is not there in dictionary so need to be removed from the string ab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in understanding that you don't want to keep key-value pairs in the string if they don't occur in the dictionary? If that's the case, you can simply parse the dictionary to that particular string format. In your case it's simply in the form `key=value;` for each entry in the dictionary:

```
ab = ''
for key, value in a.items():
    ab += "{}={};".format(key, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a new string.

I would do it by using the find method using dictionary key/values for the search.

If the value being searched for does exist, I would append to a new string

```
    s=''
    for val in a:
        word=val+'='+a[val]
        wordLen=len(word)
        x=ab.find(word)

        if x != -1:

            s+=ab[x:wordLen]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myvalue = ''
for k,v in a.items()
    myvalue = myvalue+"{}={};".format(key, value)

ab = myvalue
```

just convert the dict to desired formated string and use it. There is no need for you to remove the key as your requirement is to use the dict as it is in string format.